# How to Store Variable that is Changed In all ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, variables, uiviewcontroller, static, global-variables

I would like to try to make a variable that can be changed and accessed in all the view controllers. How should I go about doing this? I was thinking of using a static variable, or creating a global variable in one of the view controllers and passing it around, but I'm not sure if it is good practice or would be processor intensive, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a global variable to share state between view controllers, and it is actually very bad practice to hide the dependency in this way.

Make it explicit via dependency injection and pass this object from one VC to the next as you navigate.

```
SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
viewController.user = self.user; // Pass the user along...
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can do similar with segues, pass your object along inside the `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: So if I had a NSMutableArray, I should just pass that around the ViewControllers instead.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend passing around raw mutable arrays, make an object to encapsulate the array and any related state.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

1. Define your variable in `AppDelegate`
2. Use `NSUserDefault` to store/retrieve your variable
3. Use singleton class
4. Use static variable

The simplest way of course, is define it as static variable in your global `.h` file.

Global variables are not thread-safe. So, best practice is avoid using them as much as possible.